# Get an instance of static class with a private constructor through generic class

Tags: java, class, object, generics, static

I have a to get an instance of a static class, having a private constructor. MyStaticClass has a variable declared that calls the private constructor.

```
public class ImplementedClass implements TheInterface<Integer>
{
   public ImplementedClass INSTANCE = new ImplementedClass();


        private ImplementedClass(){}
        //overrides
}
```

I need to get an instance of this class from another class using generics.

```
Class<? extends TheInterface> myStaticClass = (Class<? extends TheInterface>) Class.forName(bd.getBeanClassName());
```

How can I get an instance of this class?

Comment: What arguments does the constructor expect? hint use `setAccessible(true)`

Comment: Post `MyStaticClass`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey- the class has only one constructor that is private. Private constructors are not accessible through getDeclaredConstructors or getConstructors. I can not create a new instance of the class. I somehow need to get that INSTANCE variable that shall contain the instance of the class.

Comment: Your `INSTANCE` field should be static. Otherwise things don't make sense.

Comment: @meowth isn't `INSTANCE` supposed to be `static`? Is this just an oversight in the question, or is this intentional?

Comment: @ernest_k my bad..thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want a singleton instance. 
So make the INSTANCE variable static:

```
public static ImplementedClass INSTANCE = new ImplementedClass();
```

If this is done you can:

```
    String classname="ImplementedClass";
    Class c=Class.forName(classname);
    Field instanceField=c.getDeclaredField("INSTANCE");
    TheInterface instance=(TheInterface)instanceField.get(null);
```

Comment: hey..thanks for your reply. But passing a null gives a null pointer exception

Comment: did you made INSTANCE static ? If I remove static I also get a NullPointerException.

Comment: You are right!!  It is working now. Thank you sooo much!!